# How to split blocks of terminal output into array elements that can be looped over

Tags: bash, zsh

Just looking for the best practice method to split a multi line output such as you might get from a command or a curl request into an array of entries using Bash or Zsh

For example, if a command or printing a file gave an output of

```
"User A:
    Name: Bob
    Age: 36
User B: 
    Name: Jeff
    Age: 42"
```

How would you create an array from that where each user were an entry in the array?

Or if you had an output of say devices similar to

```
"Computer A:
Name Bob's Computer
Serial 123456
Uptime 12hr
Computer B:
Name Jeff's Computer
Serial 789101
Uptime 8hr"
```

How would you split that into an array of computers, so that you could do things like see how many computers there were by the number of elements in the array, or pass them one by one to another command, etc?

I've been looking for ways to split strings and output, all the answers I find seem to target splitting a single line with a single character deliminator. I figure the way to do it is either to split by using "User" or "Computer" as the deliminator in the above examples, or to use those as a pattern to read from and to, but I'm not sure how to do that in Bash?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- You want to split the lines into e.g. "Computer A" block and "Computer B" block then store the computer (or User) names into an array.
- (May be optional) You want to parse the lines of attributes such as "Name", "Serial" ... and store them in array of arrays.

Then would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="Computer A:
Name Bob's Computer
Serial 123456
Uptime 12hr
Computer B:
Name Jeff's Computer
Serial 789101
Uptime 8hr"

keyword="Computer"                      # the keyword to split the lines into array
declare -A hash                         # create associative array
i=0                                     # index of the "real" array name

readarray -t a <<< "$str"               # read the string splitting on newlines
for line in "${a[@]}"; do               # loop over lines
    if [[ $line =~ ^${keyword}[[:blank:]]+([^:]+): ]]; then
                                        # if the line starts with the "keyword"
        name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"       # name is assigned to "A" or "B" ...
        hash[$name]="array$i"           # define "real" array name and assign the hash value to it
        declare -A "array$i"            # create a new associative array with the name above
        declare -n ref="array$i"        # "ref" is a reference to the newly created associative array
        (( i++ ))                       # increment the index for new entry
    else
        read -r key val <<< "$line"     # split on the 1st blank character
        key=${key%:}                    # remove traiking ":"
        key=${key## }                   # remove leading whitespace(s)
        ref[$key]=$val                  # store the "key" and "val" pair
    fi
done

 print number of elements of the array
echo "The array has ${#hash[@]} elements"

# print the values of each array of the array
for i in "${!hash[@]}"; do              # loop over "A" and "B"
    echo "$i"                           # print it
    declare -n ref=${hash[$i]}          # assign ref to array name "array0" or "array1" ... then make it an indirect reference
    for j in "${!ref[@]}"; do           # loop over "${array0[@]}" or "${array1[@]}" ...
        echo "  $j => ${ref[$j]}"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
The array has 2 elements
A
  Name => Bob's Computer
  Uptime => 12hr
  Serial => 123456
B
  Name => Jeff's Computer
  Uptime => 8hr
  Serial => 789101
```

Please note `bash` does not natively support array of arrays and we need to make use of `declare -n` statement to create a reference to a variable, which makes the code less readable. If `Python` is your option, please let me know. It will be much more suitable for this kind of task.

Comment: Thanks so much for this and the detailed comments :) I wish I could use python as that's my normal go to, but alas some of the machines don't have python nor perl installed, and for compliance we can't bundle them for admin tasks. This should be a great help! It looks like Zsh has a different implementation of declare, so I'll have to do some playing around to try and get a one size fits all, but you've sent me down the right track!

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick in Zsh:

```sh
split-blocks() {
  local MATCH MBEGIN MEND
  reply=(
    ${(0)1//(#m)$'\n'[^[:space:]]## [^[:space:]]##:[[:space:]]##/$'\0'$MATCH}
  ) 
}
```

What this does:

1. Find each occurrence of `<newline><text> <text>:<whitespace>`.
2. Insert a null byte before each match.
3. Split the result on null bytes.
4. Assign the resulting elements to array `$reply`.

Comment: Awsome! Thanks for that! We're not at the point yet that all the machines have Zsh, but with bash being removed from our Macs by Apple at some point, we are definitely heading that way. Simple function, easy to read, I'm definitely going to play around with it!